# iPad compatible HTML Wysiwyg editor

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, wysiwyg

Are there any iPad compatible wysiwyg HTML editors?

**Edit:** What I'm looking for is something that would work on a web app, not a native iPad app.

Comment: The funny part of this - this very editor right here, for the comment box on this web site is what I'm looking for in the iPad email interface. I don't need anything too fancy, but it sure is nice to include pics and links in an editor instead of being forced to type HTML on a dinky keyboard!

Comment: THe editor stack overflow uses is markdown based.

Comment: For those people who are coming to this from Google Search: As of 13 Sep 2011, CKEditor Version 3.6.2 Seems to support iPad with iOS 5. More details here: http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_3.6.2_released

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the GDocs editor might work, but keep in mind that there's almost no editor like that, they are managing everything by themselves.

The rest of editors try to use contentEditable, and Apple itself warns against using it with the iPad: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009577-CH1-DontLinkElementID_7

Comment: Now that iOS5 has been released you can use (or at least try, usability is the new question) the existing editors like CKEditor.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use [NicEditor](http://nicedit.com/)  which has an option of using content editable divs rather than iframe(has some issues in ipad)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there may be a few that exist. I have not had any experience with either but take a look at the below links:

iPad HTML Editor - http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kytekhtmleditor/id349354394?mt=8
SquareSpace for iPad - http://mashable.com/2010/12/21/squarespace-ipad/

Check out the following Web (html) Wysiwyg Editors.:

Dreamweaver
Flux (Mac only)
Creative Suite
Expression Web/Studio

There are a quite few available WYSIWYG editors and some are even free.  However, 'free' is not always best as the code compilation may not be optimal and important features are lacking.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a web editor, not a native iPad app.

Comment: I edited my answer...but Dreamweaver, Flux, Adobe Creative Suite, etc. are decent web editors.  Here are the open source editors: http://ckeditor.com/ and http://kompozer.net/

Comment: -1. You're still not getting it. ckeditor is along the lines of what we're looking for, but it's not iPad compatible, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but think that what you are after is something to edit the code of a web app. If it is then since the web app is essentially a web page you could use any text editor, I personally like Gusto for the iPad- http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gusto/id364906873?mt=8.

Either that or you are looking for a HTML editor which is a web app itself. In that case, sorry I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this too and couldn't find it so I coded it myself.

**[iPad web based Code Editor (with extra symbols keyboard)](http://xaviesteve.com/2928/ipad-web-based-code-editor-with-extra-symbols-keyboard/)**

It is a web-based code editor that allows you to type in all the symbols and characters used when programming (brackets, equal sign, tab, quotes...). It is currently in a very early stage so you will need to copy/paste the code, edit, copy/paste again somewhere else (Dropbox, FTP client).

You may also want to check out CodeAnywhere, they have a native app AND also a web-app.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar issue in a web app I've developed that does not allow wysiwyg editing when run on an IPad/IPhone.  The wysiwyg component I use is Telerik's RadEditor (a terrific product, btw), and Telerik has posted a KB page regarding this issue at http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/support-for-iphone-ipad-browser.aspx.  It seems, at this point, that Apple has chosen to lock down Safari on the IPad/IPhone in such a way that these rich text editors do not work.  I haven't yet seen an alternative solution to this (other than allowing IPad/IPhone users to enter their content in a plain ol' textbox) but am keeping my ear to the ground.

Comment: As I mentioned in December, iOS 5 allows the usage of WYSIWYG editors, and it has been supported in CKEditor since 3.6.2 http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_3.6.2_released Of course that support is far from perfect and there are several glitches, including the fact that typing long contents on a phone screen can be a very hard task.

Comment: You are correct.  Our team just tested the most recent version of Telerik RadEditor on iOS5 and it works like a charm.  Thanks!