# which version of ipad OS support ckeditor...?

Tags: java, javascript, ckeditor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad compatible HTML Wysiwyg editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023510/ipad-compatible-html-wysiwyg-editor)

The ckeditor version 3.6.3 which i am using does not support in the ipad, please suggest me the right version of ckeditor which does support.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question it is marked as a duplicate of. The other question is not about CKEditor and while CK is a Wysiwig editor, this question really needs to be answered for CKEditor because the companies documentation is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor has no issues with iPads, it has issues with Safari. The real question is which iOS internet browser will work properly with CKEditor? I asked the team and they said that Safari is the only one for iOS. It's not neglect towards Apple from our part since the creator of CKEditor uses an iPad!